Logistic map: bifurcation and domain of attraction
Let $f(x) = \mu x(1-x)$ be the logistic map, the question is divided into 3 parts:
Part (1): what can you say about the domain of attraction of the 2-cycle in $3<\mu<1+\sqrt 6$?
My attempt: let $x_1, x_2$ be the 2-cycle, I know that $(f^2)'(x_1) = 4+2\mu-\mu^2$ and $3,1+\sqrt 6$ are roots to $4+2\mu-\mu^2 = \pm 1$ respectively, so for $3<\mu<1+\sqrt 6$, we have $|(f^2)'(x_{1,2})|<1$, so the 2-cycle is always stable. Then I can say the domain of attraction contains at least the neighbourhood of $x_{1,2}$, but can I derive a more concise interval that must be contained in the domain of attraction?
Part (2): in the bifurcation diagram for the logistic map there are several smooth dark tracks running through the chaotic part of the diagram. What are they? (hint: think about $f(\frac{1}{2},\mu)$).

My attempt: I think the dark track signify regions where the system's dynamics, despite being predominantly chaotic, organise into periodic orbits for certain parameter ranges. However, how will thinking about $f(\frac{1}{2},\mu)$ help me in this?
Part (3): these tracks all intersect at the tip of the white wedge at $\mu \approx 3.68$. can you obtain a more precise value of $\mu$?
My attempt: I need help on this question. I don't know where to start because I don't understand what this intersection at the tip of the white wedge could represent. Could someone help me out?
Any hint or full solution are greatly appreciated!

Read this paper.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3870228/what-gives-us-the-lines-within-the-chaos-of-the-logistic-equation, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390324/what-are-the-lines-on-a-bifurcation-diagram.
