# Equation for curves of high density in bifurcation diagram

Tags: chaos-theory, bifurcation

Is there an equation for the high density curves in the chaotic regions of the bifurcation diagram for the logistic map? I'm talking about the sinusoidal-looking dark curves in the following picture. what causes these to arise?

[image]

Comment: The are the *critical curves* defined [here](https://marksmath.org/classes/Spring2019ComplexDynamics/text/subsection-critical_curves.html). See also, [The road to chaos is filled with polynomial curves](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974876).

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390324/what-are-the-lines-on-a-bifurcation-diagram